# How to use Ember CLI with old version of Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm working with an API that conforms to an older version of the JSON API spec. I know the following resources can interact with it successfully because there's another app built with them:

- Ember 1.7.0
- Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.9
- [Ember JSON API](https://github.com/kurko/ember-json-api) 1.0-beta.3
- jQuery 1.11.1

Can I use Ember CLI with these old resources?
How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using ember-cli 0.2.7 with

- "ember": "1.7.0"
- "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.10"
- "handlebars": "~1.3.0"

Its working fine.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I didn't understand your question very well, I think you are trying to build new project over some old json api spec. If that's the case then you can simply install ember cli `npm install -g ember-cli@0.2.7` and follow guide http://www.ember-cli.com/

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be something like: npm install -g ember-cli@x.x.x

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what think you will gain by downgrading ember-cli.

I would port the app to the latest Ember by creating an [adapter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html) that will take care of morphing the API data to whatever it needs to.

Otherwise, use an old ember-cli version.